# How is red-black tree insertion more effective than avl tree insertion

Tags: time-complexity, trees, avl-trees, red-black-trees

I'm having trouble understanding why RB tree insertion is called more effective in all sources.

It's said that AVL trees require "more rotations" than RB trees, but from what I've learned I can't see it. AVL trees always require one or two rotations, after which the affected subtree gets rebalanced and therefore the whole tree. We could say that rebalancing then takes O(1) but you might traverse the tree up to the root to find the point of rebalancing, so it's O(log n). Anyway, the number of rotations is constant.

In RB tree, if there is red-red conflict you might have to recolor, then recheck and then again recolor and so on, up to the root, and also after rechecking you might rotate (which also takes 1-2 rotations). So basically the same as in AVL: you might recolor up to the root, but rotation number, if it happens, is constant (right?). But in RB all this path might be longer than in AVL, since the tree isn't strictly balanced.

Where is it more effective? Simply because rotations happen statistically more rarely? Then what about having to recolor up to the root?

Comment: (Both are equally *effective*: Either something exceptional happens, or the value to be inserted is "in the tree" afterwards. Now, re. *efficiency*…YMWV.)

Comment: (It would be very helpful if *is called more [efficient] in all sources* was backed up with [who and where](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).)

Comment: @greybeard
in the last section of https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/red-black-tree-vs-avl-tree/
here first answer says that avl insertion is slower https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852870/red-black-tree-over-avl-tree
"Insertion and Deletion are complex in AVL tree as it requires multiple rotations to balance the tree."
https://www.javatpoint.com/red-black-tree-vs-avl-tree
This for some reason says that avl don't guarantee on how many rotations are required https://www.tutorialandexample.com/red-black-tree-vs-avl-tree/
and probably many more sources..

Comment: @greybeard
sorry, couldn't understand you first comment..

Comment: Also, in russian wikipedia on rb trees it's said "Insertion requires up to 2 turns in both types of trees. However, due to the greater height of the red-black tree, insertion may take longer. " Which is disproved in this article https://codedeposit.wordpress.com/2015/10/07/red-black-vs-avl/ where it's written "Insertion took significantly longer in the AVL tree than the other two, most likely due to all the rotations AVL needs to do." I'm wondering what these rotations are

Comment: `Which is disproved…` *Proof by* "anecdotal" *evidence* isn't science. As I [commented above](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144785/how-is-red-black-tree-insertion-more-effective-than-avl-tree-insertion?noredirect=1#comment305662_144785): *regarding efficiency, your mileage **will** vary* - with differences in hardware, problem parameters such as size, (JIT, possibly) compiler versions, work-arounds for [security vulnerabilities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_\(security_vulnerability\)), …

Comment: (To be fair, the codedeposit post does allow reproducing the experiments.)